# How to use Azure Logic Apps to query Salesforce Protected Accounts Entity using Email

Tags: encryption, salesforce, azure-logic-apps

[image]

When I try and filter using PersonEmail I get the following error.

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Salesforce failed to complete task: Message: \nAND (Firstname = 'Steve')) AND (PersonEmail = 'steve@gmail.com'))\n                                ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:1206\nfield 'PersonEmail' can not be filtered in a query call\r\nclientRequestId: 384fc6f7-21aa-46ce-8225-bb92a4a38ad6",
  "error": null,
  "source": "Microsoft.Azure.Connectors.Salesforce",
  "errors": []
}
```

PersonEmail is an encrypted field, so do I need to approach this differently?

Answer (score 1):

This is limitation from Salesforce end as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000ILXtQAO) that for Encrypted fields we cannot use [where clause](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_considerations_general.htm&type=5). This is the reason you are getting the error : *'PersonEmail' can not be filtered in a query call as cx confirm PersonEmail is encrypted filed*. The workaround would be, if possible, you need to replace your query from WHERE clause in a SOQL query with a FIND query in SOSL.

Comment: Is there a way to use the Salesforce Connector to execute a FIND query in SOSL?